# Upload audio blob to S3/B2 when passing through React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, next.js, blob

I'm working in Next.js 13.4's app router and with the AWS SDK for Javascript v3.

My React app records audio from a microphone and gets an audio blob. I'm having nothing but trouble trying to upload that to Amazon S3 / Backblaze B2.

I think the problem comes down to how I must pass the data to the uploader: I *must* convert the blob to a string or plain object in order to pass it from my React client component to the uploader server action.

It also seems that the AWS SDK won't let me upload anything other than a string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer.

But the real problem is in being able to convert the blob to something I can pass to the server action, and then convert it back to a correct webm file I can upload.

So I've tried doing the following in my client component:

```js
    const blobText = await blob!.text();
    await uploadFile({
      filename: "audio.webm",
      fileContent: blobText,
    });
```

That lets me pass the blobText to the server action, but even before then, if I convert `blobText` back to a blob and then download it with `URL.createObjectURL(blobTextBackToBlob)`, the result is also messed up.

That code would look like this:

```js
    const blobTextBackToBlob = new Blob([blobText], {
      type: "audio/webm", // I've tried "plain/text"
      endings: "native", // I've tried "transparent"
    });
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(blobTextBackToBlob);
```

And by "messed up," I mean that what should be 38 KB is instead 68 KB and doesn't play in VLC like the 38 KB file would (that I could download via `URL.createObjectURL` *before* converting to a string and back to a blob).

So I really think the problem is in how I'm converting the blob to text.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!